# Mock an explicit cast

Tags: c#, casting, rhino-mocks

I have two classes below. I have created a stub for the `hex` object of class `Hexagon` using Rhino Mocks in my test. If I run the test, it throws an exception when the cast operation is called on the stub.

How can I set the behaviour of the `hex` stub to allow the cast to be performed on it?

```
public class Shape
{
    //some properties and methods here
    public void PrintProperties()
    {
    }
}

public class Hexagon : Shape
{
    // some properties and methods and override
}

public static void main (string[] args)
{
    Hexagon hex = new Hexagon()

    var parentShape = (Shape)hex; // this is the explicit cast

    parentShape.PrintProperties()
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Does the answer to [this similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102911/rhino-mocks-produces-invalidcastexception-when-returning-polymorphic-object) help?

Comment: Where is your mock code?